# use preg_replace to replace character unless an escape character precedes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i'm trying to do the following hope there's a reg_ex expert around to shed some light.
I need to replace the character [ in my code and make it a {. But there is cases where the [ needs to remain a [ and not change. So the way i figured it is i need to use the

preg_replace("[", "{", $string);

function with a suitable regular expression that will result the [ characters that are not preceded by the escape character to be used lets say .
So how can i get to replace this "[" and not this "["?

thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, and it's with a convention call **negative lookbehind assertions**

```
echo preg_replace( "/(?<!\\\\)\\[/", '{', "\[ [ [ \[ [" );
```

Basically, "replace [ with { only when not preceded by \"

Comment: worked like a charm! 
thanks a lot to all of you for your time. 
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness:

There another way to do this if your regexp engine is primitive and doesn't know how to do [negative lookbehinds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374643/use-pregreplace-to-replace-character-unless-an-escape-character-precedes/1374738#1374738) (which is not the case with PHP):

```
$str = preg_replace( "/(^|[^\\\\])\\[/", '$1{', $str );
```

This captures the preceding character, which is restricted to `^` (start) or `[^\]` (any non-slash), and passes it through the replace.