# Regex Pattern required PHP - mix of strings and words

Tags: php, regex

I need help with a particular regex match. This is php. (Editing a wordpress plugin)

Let's say the string is

```
"[youtube|sjdhskajxn|This is a string|This is also a string|44|55]"
```

I want to extract

```
{0} -> youtube
{1} -> sjdhskajxn
{2} -> This is a string
{3} -> This is also a string
{4} -> 44
{5} -> 55
```

Also the number of items to be matched will not be constant.

Comment: Just use explode($delimiter, $string);

Comment: I think you need [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) by `|` sign.

Comment: That would leave the brackets, though.

Comment: Do you need to be able to escape the `|` or square brackets somehow so that a string can have a `|` in it if need be?

Comment: like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374643/use-preg-replace-to-replace-character-unless-an-escape-character-precedes

Comment: @WolfmanJoe I can't see that being a requirement. I will be in full control of the inputs.. It's highly unlikely I will have a string with | in it

Comment: If that is a wordpress plugin, rewrite it to use the [shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) - not that it is perfect (your regex is equally limited at best) - it's also the standard way to such stuff in plugins. Do no re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Waygood That's how I would begin to write a plugin but the already in existence plugin I'm using has regex. I have it working now anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$raw = '[youtube|sjdhskajxn|This is a string|This is also a string|44|55]';

// remove brackets only at beginning/end
$st = preg_replace('/(^\[)|(\]$)/', '', $raw);

$parts = explode('|', $st);
```

Comment: I know everyone touched on some part of the answer so thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = '[youtube|sjdhskajxn|This is a string|This is also a string|44|55]';
$string = str_replace(array('[',']'), '', $string); //remove brackets

$result = explode('|', $string); //explode string into an array
```

Comment: Trivially works, but it wouldn't work if you need to have `|` or the square brackets as part of the contained text, with an escape character.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function

```
$str = "[youtube|sjdhskajxn|This is a string|This is also a string|44|55]";
$str = str_replace(array('[',']'), '', $str);
$pieces = explode("|", $str);
```

Comment: `trim()` with `[]` is an alternative to `str_replace()`. It works on the ends of the string not the entire string

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow Unicode characters:

```
preg_match_all('/[\pL\pN\pZ]+/u', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

Otherwise (just ASCII), it's simpler:

```
preg_match_all('/[a-z0-9\s]+/i', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```