# how to add slashes to only double quotes

Tags: php, html

i want to add slashes to only double quotes to some html elements  this is how i am doing , but its not working for me :

```
$str  ="
    <table class="body-wrap" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <td style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;">this is my test</td></tr></table>&#13;";
```

this is my php function :

```
 $str2 = addcslashes($str, '"');
```

i think that i have problems at the beginning of my string , i dont know how to declare :

```
$str  =" or $str  = '
```

both for me didnt work

Comment: $str is not in proper formet

Comment: Why not do things properly and use a CSS stylesheet for your CSS and replace the double quotes with single quotes in your HTML syntax. `<td class='styles'>text</td>` etc.

Comment: just replace double quotes to single quotes from start and end `$str  =" ` to `$str  ='your html here with double quotes';`

Comment: first make string proper, try to use backslash \ before ", e.g. <table class=\"body-wrap\">

Comment: heredoc may convenient to handle this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete your string `$str  =" or $str  = '` as this is entirely wrong.

1) Use a CSS Style Sheet to store your CSS outside your HTML and avoid repetition.

2) Use single quotes in HTML syntax (and your PHP string is in double quotes) to avoid the need to escape your HTML at all (javascript elements will be an exception, however).

### Example of points one and two combined:

**CSS File**

```
.body_wrap_table { 
     width: 100%; 
}
.table_td_tr {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;    
      margin: 0; 
      padding: 0;
}
```

**HTML PHP String**

```
$str = " <table class='body-wrap body_wrap_table'>
    <tr class='table_td_tr'>
    <td class='table_td_tr'>this is my test</td></tr></table>
";
```

So no need for quote escaping at all.

3) If you really want to do it you can use a [Regex function](https://www.regexbuddy.com/regex.html) such as [`Preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) as exampled here:

```
$str = preg_replace('/"+(?<!\\")/', '\"', $str);
```

This regex will match any `"` character which is *not* preceeded by a `\` character, and the replace with an escaped quote.

4) A possibly simpler approach which may or may not be a solution for you (and less processor heavy than a Regex) is to simply use a str_replace such as :

```
$str = str_replace("\"","\\\",$str);
```

This replaces any text fitting the shape `"` with `\"` but this may cause double escaping if a quote already has an escape mark preceeding it.

**References:**

- [regex for matching something if it is not preceded by something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306202/regex-for-matching-something-if-it-is-not-preceded-by-something-else)
- [use preg_replace to replace character unless an escape character precedes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374643/use-preg-replace-to-replace-character-unless-an-escape-character-precedes)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a function since you are writing the HTML inside a PHP variable, you can escape the double quotes yourself, using a backslash `\"`:

```
$str  ="
<table class=\"body-wrap\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;\">
<tr style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;\">
<td style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;">this is my test</td></tr></table>&#13;";
```

The rule is: if you use single quoter `'` you need to escape single quotes only `\'`, if you use double quotes `"` then you need to escape them `\"`.

Comment: yes but OP wants a function to do this automatically, for example if the string is dynamically generated

Comment: @Martin I don't think it makes sense, because if the OP wants to use a function, he'll need to use the string as an input to the function. He would still need to escape single or double quotes to do that, or it will result in a parse error.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `$str  ="` not `$str  = '` will work. The string contains both those characters.

You can't programmatically add slashes to a broken string literal within the source code for the current program. The string literal is an error and causes the program to abort.

You need to fix it (by adding the slash characters) manually (or with the search and replace feature of your text editor).